# Jquery php mysql not APPEND with pagination

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I present my code so they can help me, I'm trying to do a shopping cart, where products from a list and then generated a table, where each row is a record (accessed from a mysql db).

I've managed to do what I need, when you click on a record, shipping GET A model form via jQuery ajax. The problem: If you use the list pagination works fine, but if I walk a place located on the page below, I results in the vector consulted and restart the index. I show the codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Listado de Productos</title>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js">          </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#paginar").live("click", function(){
    $("#contenido").html("<div align='center'><img src='imgs/cargando.gif'/></div>");
        var pagina=$(this).attr("data");
        var cadena="pagina="+pagina;

        $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url:"listar_busqueda.php",
                    data:cadena,
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                            $("#contenido").fadeIn(1000).html(data);
                    }
                });
        });
});  
  </script>

  <link href="css/tablecloth.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    /* For zebra striping */
    $("table tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd-row");
    /* For cell text alignment */
    $("table td:first-child, table th:first-child").addClass("first");
    /* For removing the last border */
    $("table td:last-child, table th:last-child").addClass("last");
  });
 </script>

 <!-- script para manejar los click en los productos y sumarlos a la tabla --->
 <script>
 var total = 0;
 $(document).ready(function() { 

      $('#form').submit(function(event){ //en el evento submit del fomulario
          event.preventDefault();  //detenemos el comportamiento por default

          var url = $(this).attr('action');  //la url del action del formulario
          var datos = $(this).serialize(); // los datos del formulario
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            data: datos,
            dataType: 'json',                //data format   
            success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
                {
                    var prodid = data[0];              //get id
                    var prodnom = data[1];           //get name
                    var proddesc = data[2];              //get id
                    var precioV = data[3];           //get name
                    var stock = data[4];           //get name
                    var cant2 = parseFloat(precioV).toFixed(2)

                    if(data == 0)
                      alert("El artículo ingresado no existe en la base de datos"); 
                         else
                            $('#tabla').append("<tr><td>"+prodid+"</td>"+"<td>"+prodnom+"</td>"+"<td>"+proddesc+"</td>"+"<td>"+precioV+"</td>"+"<td>"+stock+"</td>"+"<td>"+parseFloat(cant2).toFixed(2)+"</td>"+"</tr>")

                           total=parseFloat(total)+cant2;                   
                  } 

           });

      });   

    });
   </script>   
  </head>

  <body>
  <h2>Listado de Productos</h2>
  <table id="tabla" width="100%" border="1">
 <tr bgcolor="#F3FCB4">
<td>Codigo de producto</td>
<td>Descripcion</td>
<td>Rubro</td>
<td>Precio</td>
<td>Cantidad</td>
<td>Importe</td>
</tr>
</table>



<div id="contenido"><?php require("proces.php"); ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

/////proces.php

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");

$consulta_cantidad=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productos",$conexion);
$resultados_cantidad=mysql_num_rows($consulta_cantidad);

if ($resultados_cantidad>0)
{
$filas_pagina=10;
$numero_pagina=1;

if(isset($_GET["pagina"]))
{
    sleep(1);
    $numero_pagina=$_GET["pagina"];
}

$campo_de_inicio=($numero_pagina-1)*$filas_pagina;
$total_registros=ceil($resultados_cantidad/$filas_pagina);

echo "<table align='center'>";
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Codigo</td>";
    echo "<td>Nombre de producto</td>";
    echo "<td>Precio</td>";
    echo "<td>Stock</td>";
    echo "<td>Proveedor</td>";
    echo "<td>Accion</td>";
echo "</tr>";

$consulta=mysql_query("SELECT id,nombre,precio,stock,proveedor,id_cat FROM productos LIMIT $campo_de_inicio, $filas_pagina",$conexion);
while ($resultados=mysql_fetch_array($consulta))
{       
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$resultados["id"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$resultados["nombre"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$resultados["precio"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$resultados["stock"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$resultados["proveedor"]."</td>";
   print '<td>';          
   print '<form name="form" id="form" action="proces.php">';
   print '<input name="car" type="submit"  value="C">';
   print '<input name="cant" type="text" id="cant" value="1" size="2">';
   print '<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="'.$resultados['id'].'" size="2" >';
   print '</form>';
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";


echo "<br/>";
echo "<hr/>";

if ($total_registros>1)
{
    echo "<div align='center'>";

    if ($numero_pagina!=1)
        echo "<a id='paginar' data='".($numero_pagina-1)."'>Anterior</a> ";

        for ($i=1;$i<=$total_registros;$i++)
        {
            if($numero_pagina==$i)
            {
                echo "<a>".$i."</a> ";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<a id='paginar' data='".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
            }
        }

    if($numero_pagina!=$total_registros)
    {
        echo "<a id='paginar' data='".($numero_pagina+1)."'>Siguiente</a>";

    }

    echo "</div>";
    }
    }

    ?>
```

///productos mysql

```
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `productos`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `productos` (
`id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`desc` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`precio` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
`stock` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `proveedor` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`id_cat` int(3) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `id_cat` (`id_cat`),
KEY `id_cat_2` (`id_cat`),
KEY `id_cat_3` (`id_cat`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1539 ;
```

Comment: Please come up with a better title. Something other than merely reiterating the question tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is because your variable is set on javascript and nothing more..
you could use cookies to solve this.
[This is $.cookie](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) and it can help you to solve your problem.
Instead of

```
var total = 0;
```

it would be something like

```
$.cookie('total',0)
```

and everytime you want to modify it or read, just do it

```
$.cookie('total',$.cookie('total')++);  
alert('Total actual: '+$.cookie('total'));
```

Comment: the problem is append a new <tr> in table before navigate the pagination

Comment: i still don't understand your english, maybe spanish?